# PlaceAutocompleteFragment: automatically open SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, google-places

I want to automatically click on a fragment as soon as the activity is done loading.

The fragment definition is:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    />
```

I have tried doing this

```
fragment = findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fragment.performClick();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

but it didnt work.

Is there any way to click automatically on a fragment?

EDIT:
In my case, the fragment is inflated by

```
//PlaceAutoComplete Search Implementation
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);


    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.i(String.valueOf(this), "Place: " + place.getName() + "\nID: " + place.getId());
            String placeId = place.getId();
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PlaceSearch.this, PlaceDetailsFromSearch.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("placeID", placeId);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.i(String.valueOf(this), "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen after click?

Comment: please check this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RfQOrSlqPs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I don't want to manually click on fragment because it is kinda unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot click on a `<fragment>`.

Click event is something that only `View` can have. Fragment is **not** a `View`.

You can click on a `View` that your fragment inflates.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
    // some `View` from your fragment
    View searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView); 
    // Dispatch a click event to `searchView` as soon as that view is laid out
    searchView.post(() -> searchView.performClick());
}
```

## Update

Because you are using `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` which is from Play Services (thus you do not have sources), you can do something like this in your activity:

```
final PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

final View root = autocompleteFragment.getView();
root.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        root.findViewById(R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input)
                .performClick();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, I have updated my code. 
Included the method that is inflating the fragment.

Don't know how can I get a reference to that :/

Comment: I tried to do what you asked but I get an error saying "Lambda Expressions are not available at this language level"

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin :
for latest Places api 2.4.0 (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0)
you can get view and then perform click on searchview by following code :

```
val root: View = autocompleteSupportFragment?.view!!
root.findViewById<View>(R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input).performClick()
```